# How can I use sed to replace a word between periods without spaces?

Tags: sed

I have a large document (Johnson's DICTIONARY OF THE ENGLISH LANGUAGE) that has a large number of typos in this format:

> MITHRIDATE (MI'THRIDATE) n.s.[mithridate, Fr.] Mithridate is one of the capital medicines of the shops, consisting of a great number of ingredients, and has its name from its inventor Mithridates, king of Pontus.Quincy.

where there is a proper name like Quincy beginning with a capital letter surrounded by periods that do not have spaces.

I want to change all the occurrences like `.Quincy.` to `. Quincy.` without changing the items like `n.s.` to `n. s.`.

I am willing to ignore the possibly lacking space after the `s.` in `n.s.[mithridate]`.

I have tried various combinations of character classes and back references without success.

Comment: `sed -E 's/\.([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+\.)/. \1/g'` might work, but it's hard to tell from a single example.

Comment: Did @BenjaminW. s comment work for you? If not, could you describe in which way it was not satisfying? If yes, would you like to create an answer, to make a Q/A pair?